# Ranking in the binary trees

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity, binary-tree

I have a binary tree, the node has two subtrees, every node except the the leaves, has 2 children and all the leaves are at the same level.

I want to know the worst and best case complexities when I applied centralized ranking to this type of tree. (defined above)

For the worst case, O(n^2) happens when the tree is chain. But what about this kind of tree? What is the best and worst case complexities of this kind of tree?

Comment: how this tree could be a chain if you said above, that every node has 2 children? could you give an example of this tree?

Comment: [Crossposted to cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30248/ranking-in-binary-trees) (where it fits the scope much better).